# Showing multiple info boxes in Google Maps when pulling from MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps

I have the following code and have been stuck on this issue for a very long time. I'm able to display the multiple markers but cannot get them to display the info details when clicked within a pop up info box. Right now I'm trying to get it to say "Hey!" as a test. Any suggestions is appreciated!

```js
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer>
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
  
  var image = 'images/marker_blast.png';
  
   
  
        function initialize() {
            // Set static latitude, longitude value
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.4313684, -79.9805005);
            // Set map options
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 11,
                center: latlng,
                panControl: true,
                zoomControl: true,
                scaleControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            // Create map object with options
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
   
   //MARK MAP
    <?php
    $markers = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM reports");
      
    while($row_marker = $markers->fetch_assoc()) {
     
     // uncomment the 2 lines below to get real data from the db
     // $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parkings");
     // while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      echo "addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(".$row_marker['lat'].", ".$row_marker['lng']."), map);\n";
      
      
      
    
    }
    ?>
    }
 
    
    function addMarker(latLng, map) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      size:30,
      draggable: false, // enables drag & drop
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
     });
       
    }
    
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker) {  
          return function() {  
           var content = "Hey";  
           infowindow.setContent(content);  
           infowindow.open(map, marker);  
          }  
        })(marker));  
    
 
        </script>
```

Comment: You're unable to display multiple infoWindow at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the InfoWindow to the marker in the `addMarker` function where the marker exists:

```
function addMarker(latLng, name,  map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        size: 30,
        draggable: false, // enables drag & drop
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function (marker) {
      return function () {
        var content = "Hey "+name;
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker));
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/teLep7uo/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if echoing the function inside the while loop will make it run like you want it to. Consider a method like this.

```
<?php while($row_marker = $markers->fetch_assoc()) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parkings");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

        addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row_marker['lat']; ?>, <?php echo $row_marker['lng']; ?>), map);

    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're running the second while loop but it doesn't look like you're using the result `$row` at all.